# Transparent colors, how does it work?

Tags: graphics, transparency

Just a question across programming languages. If I make a color transparent in an image, does it mean that affected pixels are not displayed at all? Ie the processing just skips the pixels with color that is set as transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the image is displayed on top of a background (be it a plain background or another image), the background will be visible through the transparent pixels of your image.

Comment: Sorry I did not make myself clear. I know how it will look like..but I would like to know whether the processing just skips the pixels with color that is set as transparent?

Comment: This is an implementation detail: read the source of your particular display program. :-/ It may depend on the low-level API it is using, on whether alpha compositing is available, on whether it is optimized for or not, on the mood of whoever wrote the code, etc.